# Transferring jira users to crowd in jira-crowd-postgresql containers running in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, jira, atlassian-crowd

I have two servers running docker containers. jira and postgres works in a container with docker compose. In the other, the crowd works. Jira already hosts active users. I want to distribute these users through the crowd. So I want to transfer users on jira to crowd. I am using Atlassian product importer for this process. However, the Atlassian product importer cannot access JIRA's database.

---

### Server1

Crowd container

---

### Server2

Jira Container

Postgres Container

---

I follow the steps in this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowd/importing-users-from-atlassian-jira-30736459.html). But the connection fails. I don't understand why. Did the error cause products to work with the docker? or is it to be on different servers? Can you help with solving this problem?

[image]

I've checked the contact information over and over again and I'm sure it's correct.

Comment: Take a look at pg_hba.conf. Perhaps postgres in Jira container just doesn't allow connections except localhost.